# How to adjust min-width and max-width simultaneously in twitter-bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my css to be applied for only between 544px -  768px width. How can I use bootstrap @media feature on this purpose? I have tried something like in the following example but it didn't work:

```
@media (min-width:544px || max-width:768px)  { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
@media (max-width:768px) and (min-width:544px) {

}​
```

Answer (score 1):

The media query syntax will be:

```
 @media screen and (min-device-width: 544px ) and (max-device-width: 768px) {
   //Your CSS here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your case -

```
@media all and (max-width: 544px) and (min-width: 768px) {}
```